# Mule ESB - Java source code class that manages messages on the queue

Tags: java, mule, esb

What java class, in the Mule ESB source code, manages access to the queue messages? Like, for example, moving a message from the queue and passing it further in the flow to be processed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component that does the process of picking from the queue and passing it to the flow to be processed is WorkManager.

Extract from Mule Soft site

> Furthermore, each message waiting in the queue can be assigned a
>   different thread from a pool of threads. A component called a Work
>   Manager assigns pending messages to available threads, so they can be
>   processed in parallel.

Comment: Sorry, I can not vote up the answer - my reputation is 3 (new user), and to vote up it is required 15.